# I want to Update User Claims in IdentityServer4 (.NET Core 3.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

#### Problem:

I want to refresh user claims in identity server 4. I have made an API endpoint in identity server project. This API endpoint is given below. After that I call the UserInfoEndpoint and RefreshTokenEndpoint from my Angular Client using oidc-client.js library. I get the refreshtoken and new accesstoken but the claims in the response are old. I have to relogin in my client and identity server to reload the updated claims.

#### API Code

```cs
   if (ModelState.IsValid && model.IsSelected && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    var user = _userRepository.GetUserByAppId(model.UserId);
                    user.AccessCode = model.Code; // A simple 3 digit code
                    var updatedUser = _userRepository.UpdateUser(user); //updating it in the dB
                    var claimsResult = _userRepository.GetUserClaims(updatedUser);
                    if (!claimsResult.IsSuccess)
                    {
                        return BadRequest(new { Status = false, Message = "Failed To Change" });
                    }
                    var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                    string[] claimsTobeUpdated = { "AccessCode" };
                    foreach (var item in identity.Claims.ToList())
                    {
                        if (claimsTobeUpdated.Contains(item.Type))
                        {
                            identity.RemoveClaim(item);
                            var claim = claimsResult.Claims.Where(p => p.Type == item.Type).FirstOrDefault();
                            identity.AddClaim(claim);
                        }
                    } // I was updating more than one claims thats why I'm iterating
                    AuthenticationProperties props = new AuthenticationProperties()
                    {
                        IsPersistent = true,
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration),
                    };

                    // issue authentication cookie with subject ID and username
                    var isuser = new IdentityServerUser(user.Id.ToString())
                    {
                        DisplayName = user.Name,
                        AdditionalClaims = claimsResult.Claims.ToList(),
                    };
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, props);


                    var claims = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity; // here I've checked that the claims updated or not and these are updated.

                    return Ok(new { Status = true, Message = "Changed Successfully" });
                }
```

#### Desired Output:

I want to have same claims in my identity server session as well as the API and Ng session. if you can help me it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Ahmed Naeem, you can check the code that generates the refreshtoken and a new access token, whether it generates the refreshtoken with the new claims?

Comment: Good day Qing, I have tried the refresh token thing, requested the new access token from my Angular Client but Profile (User Claims) are not refreshing, the new access token and the refresh token in replaced successfully

Answer (score 0):

You should check settings of your client api in Identity Server.(https://docs.identityserver.io/en/3.1.0/topics/refresh_tokens.html)

Check that this property (`UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh`) is set to true.

This value indicates whether the access token (and its claims) should be updated on a refresh token request.